# Historically, when was whitespace used versus interpuncts versus no-separation?

Tags: historical-linguistics, writing-systems, words, semitic-languages, punctuation

The [Wikipedia article on whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Space_(punctuation)&diff=prev&oldid=1126868827) claimed until recently that the use of whitespace as a word separator was rare until its promotion by Alcuin of York in the Carolingian Renaissance. But I've found photographs of the Dead Sea Scrolls, which date to between 100BC and 100AD, and the words are clearly all separated by whitespace, instead of interpuncts. I've now made edits both to the [whitespace article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Space_(punctuation)&diff=prev&oldid=1126868827) and to the [talk page on word dividers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Word_divider) to express my doubts. Does anyone have information about the usage of whitespace versus interpuncts versus no-dividers in pre-medieval Semitic languages like Phoenician, Hebrew and Aramaic?

[image: Genesis 1-8, Hebrew and its English translation]

---

I've just found [Are there spaces or other marks between word in Ancient Semitic epigraphs?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/41829/are-there-spaces-or-other-marks-between-word-in-ancient-semitic-epigraphs) by following the question tags, and it already seems much more plausible than Wikipedia. Someone should update Wikipedia.

Comment: Whitespace was also fairly standard in Hittite cuneiform, sometimes called "Schreibmaschinen-Keilschrift" (typewriter cuneiform) for the careful separation of signs and words.

Comment: Maybe I can finally get an answer to this question... https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/39760/textual-organization